# Vertical black line next to <video> in Edge

Tags: html, video, cross-browser

Demonstration: https://puu.sh/BOLZV/7f4dca58d2.mp4 (Firefox, then Edge shown)

Code:

```
<center>
<h1 style="font-family: times new roman">Electricity & Magnetism</h1>
<video autoplay loop height="300px" src="../Images/stuff.mp4"></video>
</center><hr>
```

Found no way to rid of the vertical line; +/- padding doesn't do, and the source video doesn't have the black line. Works fine in Firefox and Edge (other browsers not tested).

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Is  https://puu.sh/BOLZV/7f4dca58d2.mp4 the original video?
If yes, chrome, edge, FF all appear horizontal line at left-bottom in 0:05 and vertical line in 0:06. I believe there is some problem in catching this video, not the html tag setting.

[image]

Comment: The 'line' is a preview window coming into the capture area as I tabbed between the browsers.